# Segmentation fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qt-creator, qtgui

I am trying to build MainWindow with some toolbars and menus. 
So in my mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QToolBar;
class QStatusBar;


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    MainWindow();

 protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

 private slots:
     void open();
     void save();
//void updateStatusBar();

 private:
     void createToolbars();
     void createActions();
     void createMenus();
     void createStatusBar();
 bool loadFile(const QString &fileName);
 bool saveFile(const QString &fileName);

 QToolBar *filetBar;
 QAction *openAction;
 QAction *saveAction;
 QAction *separatorAction;
 QAction *exitAction;
 QStatusBar *stsBar;
 QMenu *fileMenu;
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I have private variables QToolbar * filetBar;
And in .cpp file, 
I am calling:
createToolbars which is:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMdiArea>
#include <QMdiSubWindow>
#include <QAction>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QToolButton>
```

//#include "mdichild.h"

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow()
 {
    mdiArea = new QMdiArea;
    mdiArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    mdiArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    setCentralWidget(mdiArea);

    createToolbars();
    createActions();
    createMenus();
    createStatusBar();

    setWindowTitle(tr("GUI OPTIMIZER"));
    setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/up.jpeg"));
   }
   void MainWindow::createActions()
   {
     openAction = new QAction(QIcon(":images/open.png"), tr("&Open"), this);
     openAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Open);
     openAction->setStatusTip(tr("Open your gui (*.al) file"));
     connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));

     saveAction = new QAction(QIcon(""), tr("&Save"), this);
saveAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Save);
saveAction->setStatusTip(tr("Save optimized gui"));
connect(saveAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(save()));

exitAction = new QAction(QIcon(""), tr("&Close"), this);
exitAction -> setShortcut(QKeySequence::Close);
connect(exitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

   }

   void MainWindow::createToolbars()
   {
     filetBar = new QToolBar("File", this);
     filetBar = addToolBar(tr("&File"));
     filetBar->addAction(openAction);

   }

   void MainWindow::createMenus()
   {
      fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
      fileMenu->addAction(openAction);
      fileMenu->addAction(saveAction);
      separatorAction = fileMenu->addSeparator();
      fileMenu->addSeparator();
      fileMenu->addAction(exitAction);
   }
```

When I run, it just says The program has unexpectedly finished.
When I run it with debugger is gives me

Signal name : SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
ad line

It show menus, and actions are working. 
Any idea how can I fix it?
Thanks. 
`

Comment: filetBar = new QToolbar (this); ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still the error.

Comment: When I for example do MainWindow::addToolbar(tr("&File")); it creates toolbar and no errors. I really do not know what is wrong here. And I partially took the code from example of qt-project MainWindow.

Comment: Where do you initialize your QActions?

Comment: I might get it wrong, but I create Actions in createActions() function, or initializing means something else?

Comment: In the code you posted you only initialize `openAction`.

Comment: Can you more specific? I do not know what you mean? I have other actions, but I did not implement them yet, I just want to get working and add other actions,

Comment: Well it won't work until you either implement all actions or stop using those that are not yet implemented. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that each of your member variables is initialized in the constructor to some sensible value before using them. This means that for each of these:

```
 QToolBar *filetBar;
 QAction *openAction;
 QAction *saveAction;
 QAction *separatorAction;
 QAction *exitAction;
 QStatusBar *stsBar;
 QMenu *fileMenu;
```

You need to have a corresponding:

```
filetBar = new QToolBar( /* ... */ );
```

In particular you are passing uninitialized `QAction` objects to your widgets. In your constructor, or in a separate method called from the constructor you should have a code like the following:

```
 openAction = new QAction("&Open", this);
 saveAction = new QAction("&Save", this);
 // etc.
```

Comment: I added fileTbar = new QToolbar(this),

Comment: And also other actions, and I guess, I have all my actions created as you have said, but I just have QIcon for them,

Comment: still, the segmentation error at the line filetBar->addAction(openAction)

Comment: I do not think it is about QActions, my actions are working fine, since in Menu there are working as they should. So the problem is something with QToolbar, I do not know what.

Comment: How do you know your actions are working fine if you're not able to start the program?

Comment: When the function createToolbars() is empty literally, the programm starts, or when I just comment the function, it works, and when I have inside my function just filetBar = addToolbar(tr("&File"), the prgoram works just fine, only when I addAction to filetBar, it crashes.

Comment: In your constructor call `createActions()` before `createToolbars()`.

Comment: You are my saver.I just did not think Qt works like this.Thank you.I do not know how things work here, like if I can vote for your answer or something?

Comment: C++ in general works this way. You need to initialize variables before using them. You can accept the answer above by clicking a green tick.